Why dig is answering SERVFAIL, while nslookup resolving normally on powerdns local zone?
I'm a bit new to local DNS so i want to use 1 node with ip 192.168.100.11 and auth + recursor + dnsdist at one host. Auth server should resolve only local zone (holodev.local in my case), recursor should resolve everything that not local and forward it to public dns servers. I configured the .local zone via PowerAdmin and added the reverse zone 100.168.192.in-addr.arpa which contains SOA record and PTR for my nextcloud '98.100.168.192.in-addr.arpa PTR nextcloud.holodev.local'. The main zone contains ns1 and ns2 (i'm not shure about using ns2 at 1 node) records, SOA and A for nextcloud. I have the following configs:
pdns.conf
[root@dns ~]# sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' /etc/pdns/pdns.conf 
dnsupdate=yes
launch=gmysql 
gmysql-host=localhost 
gmysql-user=pda 
gmysql-password=dnsdbpas1
gmysql-dbname=pda
local-address=127.0.0.1
local-port=5300
log-dns-queries=yes
security-poll-suffix=
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns

recursor conf
[root@dns ~]# sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' /etc/pdns-recursor/recursor.conf 
disable-syslog=no
forward-zones=holodev.local=127.0.0.1:5300
forward-zones-recurse=.=8.8.8.8
local-address=127.0.0.1
local-port=5301
logging-facility=1
loglevel=6
quiet=no
security-poll-suffix=
setgid=pdns-recursor
setuid=pdns-recursor

dnsdist conf
[root@dns ~]# sed '/^\s*--/d;/^\s*$/d' /etc/dnsdist/dnsdist.conf 
setSecurityPollSuffix("")
setLocal('192.168.100.11')
addLocal('127.0.0.1')
newServer({address='127.0.0.1:5301', name="recursor"})
newServer({address='127.0.0.1:5300', name="authoritive", pool={"auth"}})
setServerPolicy(firstAvailable)
pc = newPacketCache(10000, {maxTTL=86400, minTTL=0, temporaryFailureTTL=60, staleTTL=60, dontAge=false})
getPool(""):setCache(pc)
addAction(NotRule(OrRule({makeRule("192.168.0.0/16"), makeRule("127.0.0.1")})), DropAction())

Dig output (Im using the CT under the same hypervisor, but ip is different and only 1 dns server in resolve.conf). And interesting for me that outside zones working fine
[root@zabbix ~]# dig holodev.local @192.168.100.11

; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> holodev.local @192.168.100.11
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 7871
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;holodev.local.                 IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.100.11#53(192.168.100.11)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 26 02:43:05 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42

----------------------------

[root@zabbix ~]# dig google.com @192.168.100.11

; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> google.com @192.168.100.11
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12312
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             57      IN      A       142.250.203.206

;; Query time: 75 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.100.11#53(192.168.100.11)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 26 02:53:12 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55

nslookup
[root@zabbix ~]# nslookup nextcloud.holodev.local 192.168.100.11
Server:         192.168.100.11
Address:        192.168.100.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   nextcloud.holodev.local
Address: 192.168.100.98

What I'm missunderstanding and what causing status: SERVFAIL? I can curl and ping the domain too.

The .local TLD is reserved for mDNS, don't use it with normal DNS.

Yes, I know it. But can this cause the dig error?
